# Rails and Active Storage, how to assign attachment directly on the create call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I have `MyModel` with:

```
has_one_attached :video
```

I see I can do this:

```
my_model = MyModel.create!()
my_model.video.attach(io: File.open("path/my_video.webm"), filename: "video.webm")
```

And it works properly.

But I am wondering if there is a way of doing the attachment assignation into the `create()` call like:

```
MyModel.create!(
  video: File.read("path/my_video.webm")
)
```

If I do the above I see this error:

> /.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/message_verifier.rb:176:in `verify': ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature (ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature)

I've tried this:

```
MyModel.create!(
  video: File.open("path/my_video.webm")
)
```

I am get this error:

> /.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activestorage-6.1.4.1/lib/active_storage/attached/changes/create_one.rb:74:in `find_or_build_blob': Could not find or build blob: expected attachable, got #File:/Users/fernando.guillen/Development/PlaycocolaBackend/test/fixtures/files/video.webm (ArgumentError)

Comment: What `my_model.video.attach` does is it created an `ActiveStorage::Blob` and an `ActiveStorage::Attachment`. It then links the attachment to both the blob and your model.  As to your question, I'm not sure it's possible to set up a full HABTM trio of records like that.

Comment: Besides, what are you trying to achieve here? Even if it is possible in ActiveRecord (bundle it in one ruby call), it's still three inserts to the database.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I am looking for compact code and, specially, coherence. Has not sense to me that all the other attributes are assigned in the create() call and this one is assigned latter. In my example I have removed the other attributes but in the real code MyModel has several and they are all assigned into the create() call

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it by creating an instance of `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile`. This is basically just a wrapper around a tempfile instance which Rails uses internally when dealing with file uploads.

```
MyModel.create!(
  video: ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new(
    tempfile: File.open("path/my_video.webm"), 
    filename: "video.webm",
    content_type: 'video/webm'
  )
)
```

In terms of efficiency or LOC it doesn't really have any advantages over calling `.attach`. It is a nifty trick though for dealing with files passed as base64 encoded strings in JSON.

Answer (score 4):

You can also `MyModel.create!(video: { io: File.open('some/path'), filename: 'video.webm' })`

Answer (score 0):

A "real" use case for this: using [factories](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot) to create records which validate the attachment's presence on create.

You can use `Rack::Test::UploadedFile` for this:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :my_model do
    video { Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(Rails.root.join("path", "my_video.webm"), "video/webm") }
  end
end
```